Migration to .NET 6 and routing problems
I used .NET Upgrade Assistant to upgrade an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application to .NET 6.0. And I started having routing problems such as

No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

and

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found

After removing Identity authentication annotations from the controller.

I added services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false); to the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs but it didn't work.

I also tried to replace app.UseMvc() by app.UseEndpoints() (check below) but the problem still persists.
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "default",
             template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });

 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "default",
             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });



Does anyone have any hint on how I can solve this?
Thanks.

I would try to create default mvc template and copy pipeline setup from it.

I did that but a new .NET 6 project has no Setup.cs, and I got a lot of errors when trying to put all the configurations in Program.cs.

In .Net 6, you need add routing in Program.cs like below:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
      
var app = builder.Build();
    
app.UseRouting();    
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Then check the list of packages that your project contains and be sure that  outdated version packages are not part of the project, for example:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. I mean   remove the outdated version packages in your migrated project.

What should I do with startup.cs since it was a migration?

Hi @BrunoCorreia, for .net 6, no need use startup.cs any more. Just remove it and use Program.cs instead.
